# В Laravel/vue.js приложении проверку с Dusk

Tags: vue.js, laravel5, testng

Всем привет,
В Laravel 5.5/vue.js2.5  приложении делаю проверку с помощью Dusk :

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->resize(1920, 1080); // Width and Height
    $new_document_category= 'new document category created at ' . time();
    $browser->loginAs(User::find(5))
    ->visit('/admin/dashboard#/admin/document_categories/edit/new')
    ->type('#name', $new_document_category) // Поле заполняется ->type , но НЕ заполняется если ->value
    ->select('#type', 'D')
    ->value('#document_category_content', $new_document_category .' content lorem...')
    ->click('.editor_button_submit')
    ->assertTitleContains('Tasks/Chats/Events')
    ->assertPathIs('/admin/dashboard#/admin/document_categories');
});
```

Это Vuejs 2.5 приложение с настройкой рутов:

```
const routes = [
    {
    path: '/',
    ...
    {path: '/admin/document_categories', component: DocumentCategoriesIndex, name: 'documentCategoriesIndex'},
    {path: '/admin/document_categories/edit/:id', component: DocumentCategoryEdit, name: 'editDocumentCategory'},
    ...
]

const router = new VueRouter( {
    mode: 'hash', // default
    routes
})
```

И при открытии формы для создания открывается урл :

```
http://local-tasks.com/admin/dashboard#/admin/document_categories/edit/new
```

И при сохранении переходит на

```
http://local-tasks.com/admin/dashboard#/admin/document_categories
```

Тест работает но на последний assertPathIs получаю ошибку :

```
Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::testBasicExample
Failed asserting that '/admin/dashboard' matches PCRE pattern "/^\/admin\/dashboard#\/admin\/document_categories$/u".
```

Почему и как ее исправить ?

Спасибо !

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Здесь принято задавать по одному вопросу в вопросе)) Пожалуйста, создайте отдельный вопрос для каждого из трёх подвопросов.

Comment: Текст поста подправил